# SSMS database diagram

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

I have an sql database with more than 50 table. I have worked for the past two days creating relationships on my local server, and now need to export that diagram to the server. is this possible at all? I am using sql server 2012 express.

Comment: You need to export the diagrams or the "relationships" (key constraints?)? Why would you need diagrams on another server?

Comment: You already have something on server ? Wanna "update" the server's database, or create a new (empty or not) database ?

Comment: I want to update. The database schemas are exactly the same. Just, the relationships were not defined

Comment: I need the key contraints transferred to the server!

Answer (score 0):

Edited after confirmation this helped:

->  You can copy the diagram to the clipboard by selecting Copy Diagram to Clipboard from the Database Diagrams menu option (Right click the white space when the Diagram is open).  I've tried this on SSMS 2008 and it works, as long as you don't need to edit it afterwards.

->  I don't recommend this but for exporting and importing - [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/5587-sql-server-export-import-diagram) maybe of some assistance but I haven't tried it (it involves exporting the contents of dtproperties).

Comment: Am able to copy the diagram to clipboard, but I am not able to use it on the server database.

Comment: As expected unfortunately, try following the link in the answer above.  However I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Good news, next time I would avoid it - perhaps use SQL rather than do it diagrammatically.  Having never done it, check the constraints are actually ok??  I am concerned it only exported the diagram?